The asymptotic of an integral $I$

Consider the integral
$$
I(\lambda)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{v}}\,\left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{i\lambda u (u^2-v)}}{\sqrt{u^2+ 4v}}\,\varphi(u,v)\, du\right) dv,
$$
where $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $\varphi(0)\ne 0$, $\varphi\equiv 0$ when $|u|>1$ or $|v|>1$.


I want to get the asymptotic of $I$ as $\lambda\rightarrow \infty$, this integral comes from another oscillatory integral, I simplify it to $I$, and
I guess $I\approx \lambda^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ as $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$. Moreover, I want to know the limit $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow \infty}\lambda^{\frac{1}{3}} I(\lambda)$.

My thought (for special $\varphi$): note that the double integral is absolutely convergent. I write $u= \sqrt{v}\,t$ and exchange the order
\begin{align}
 I &= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{v}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{e^{i \lambda v^{\frac{3}{2}}t(t^2-1)}}{\sqrt{t^2+4}} \varphi(\sqrt{v}\,t,v)\, dt \, dv\\
 &= \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{i\lambda v^{\frac{3}{2}}t(t^2-1)}}{\sqrt{v}}\varphi(\sqrt{v}\, t,v) \, dv\,dt\quad (\mbox{then let}\ w=v^{\frac{3}{2}})\\
&= \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+4}} \left(\int_0^\infty e^{i\lambda w\, t(t^2-1)}\, w^{-\frac{2}{3}} \varphi(w^{\frac{1}{3}}t,w^{\frac{2}{3}})\,dw\right)\,dt=:\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}J(\lambda,t)\,dt.
\end{align}
Since $t(t^2-1)$ has roots $0,\pm 1$, near $0$ we split (for some small $c\in (0,1)$ and large $N>1$)
$$
I=\int_{|t|<\lambda^{-1}} + \int_{\lambda^{-1}<|t|<c} + \int_{c<|t|<N}+ \int_{|t|>N}=I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4.
$$
$I_1$ is easy since $\varphi\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $w^{-\frac{2}{3}}$ is integrable near $0$, which gives a bound $O(\lambda^{-1})$.
For $I_2$, we know $|\lambda t(t^2-1)|\approx 1$, thus we choose $\varphi$ properly (for example, $\varphi=\varphi(u^6,v^6)$) and by the method of stationary phase,
$$
J(\lambda,t) \approx (\lambda t(t^2-1))^{-\frac{1}{3}} \varphi(0,0)\approx \lambda^{-\frac{1}{3}} t^{-\frac{1}{3}}.
$$
For $I_3$, we can repeat the argument above to handle the zeros $\pm 1$.
For $I_4,$ we only consider $\int_N^\infty$, let $z= w t^3$, then
$$
J(\lambda,t) = t^{-1}\int_0^\infty e^{i\lambda z (1-t^{-2})} z^{-\frac{2}{3}} \varphi(z^{\frac{1}{3}},\frac{z^{\frac{2}{3}}}{t^2})\,dz \approx t^{-1} \lambda^{-\frac{1}{3}}.
$$
In the last step we used the method of stationary phase and the fact that $1-t^{-2}\approx 1$. Thus
$$
I_4 \approx \lambda^{-\frac{1}{3}}\int_N^\infty \frac{1}{t \sqrt{t^2+4}}\,dt \approx \lambda^{-\frac{1}{3}}.
$$
(Is the above argument valid?)

Denote
$$I(\lambda) \equiv \int_{\Bbb{R}\times(0,1)} \frac{e^{i\lambda u(u^2-v)}}{\sqrt{u^2v+4v^2}}\varphi(u,v)dudv$$
and use the substitution $\left(\lambda^{\frac{1}{3}}u,\lambda^{\frac{2}{3}}v\right) = (s,t)$ to obtain
$$I(\lambda) = \int_{\Bbb{R}\times\left(0,\lambda^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)}\frac{e^{is(s^2-t)}}{\sqrt{s^2t+4t^2}}\varphi\left(\frac{s}{\lambda^{\frac{1}{3}}},\frac{t}{\lambda^{\frac{2}{3}}}\right)\frac{dsdt}{\lambda^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
which means
$$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\lambda^{\frac{1}{3}}I(\lambda) = \varphi(0,0)\int_{\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{R}^+}\frac{e^{is(s^2-t)}}{\sqrt{s^2t+4t^2}}dsdt = M\cdot\varphi(0,0)$$
In other words
$$I(\lambda) \sim \lambda^{-\frac{1}{3}}$$
as desired.

Thanks! How to show $|M|<\infty$?

@cbi Integrate on consecutive intervals $I_n$ that you cleverly choose to apply the alternating series test on the resulting sum.

May your show a little more details about this in the answer?

@cbi why don't you put in the effort to try it first and I can provide pointers. If you want an easier problem to understand how the procedure works, try proving the integral of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ converges.

How do you justify the interchange of limit and integral in this case, as $\lambda\to\infty$?
